# Inequality between two similar definite integrals of Taylor remainders

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, analytic-functions

I am working through Markushevich's Book 1 and I am struggling to see how to prove this inequality.

The goal is to show that for some infinitely differentiable function $f$ on a neighborhood of $x_0$, such that $f^{(k)}(x) \geq 0$ for all $k$, we have that $f(x)$ is analytic.

Following the hint, taking $x_0 - \epsilon < a < x < b < x_0 + \epsilon$, it is clear to me that $0 \leq R_n(x) \leq f(x)$, which is crucial to squeezing $R_n(x) \to 0$ after we show the following:
$$ R_n(x) \leq \left(\frac{x - a}{b - a}\right)^{n + 1} R_n(b). $$

If we take the second form of the equality suggested by the hint, the resulting inequality (that I am unable to reason about) looks like
$$ \int_0^1 f^{(n + 1)}((x - a)u + a)(1 - u)^n \, du \leq
\frac{x - a}{b - a} \int_0^1 f^{(n + 1)}((b - a)u + a)(1 - u)^n \, du, $$
which follows from
$$ \begin{aligned}
R_n(x) &= \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(x - t)^n \, dt \\
&= \frac{(x - a)^n}{n!} \int_0^1 f^{(n + 1)}((x - a)u + a)(1 - u)^n \, du, \\
\end{aligned} $$
coming from $u = \dfrac{t - a}{x - a}$.

Are there any suggestions for how to proceed with proving the inequality? Trying the same $u$ substitution on both integrals is difficult because one of them uses $x - t$ and the other is $b - t$.

EDIT: I have computed the following, but the deletion of $\left(\dfrac{x - t}{b - t}\right)^n \leq 1$ doesn't feel quite right to me, but it might be correct?
$$ \begin{aligned}
R_n(x) &= \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(x - t)^n \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \frac{(x - t)^n}{(b - t)^n} \, dt \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \, dt \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^b f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \, dt \\
\end{aligned} $$

EDIT #2: Ok, so it looks like I was on the right track. We instead use the inequality $\dfrac{x - t}{b - t} \leq \dfrac{x - a}{b - a}$ (clearing fractions and simplifying yields $(t - a)(b - x) \geq 0$ which is obviously true). Then we get
$$ \begin{aligned}
R_n(x) &= \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(x - t)^n \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \frac{(x - t)^n}{(b - t)^n} \, dt \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^x f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \, dt \\
&\leq \left(\dfrac{x - a}{b - a}\right)^n \frac{1}{n!} \int_a^b f^{(n + 1)}(t)(b - t)^n \, dt \\
&= \left(\dfrac{x - a}{b - a}\right)^n R_n(b), \\
\end{aligned} $$
which seems different than what the book wanted me to prove, and could perhaps be a typo, which I originally believed to be typo'd for incorrect reasons. In retrospect, probably not a typo because there is still some funny business that was never dealt with as we fudge $x \to b$. $(b - t)^n$ remains positive and $f^{(k)}(t)$ is also positive so the value can only increase, but perhaps the extra power is the factor by which it can increase.

Comment: Re: the edit...why does it not feel right to you? Can you explain a little more on that (it looks right to me).

Comment: What ends up happening is we get $R_n(x) \leq R_n(b)$, which is not strong enough.